# web scrape does not find the correct tags

Tags: pandas, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract the text of this page: https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033 using bs4 and pandas

I start with:

```
src=requests.get(url).content
soup = BeautifulSoup(src,'xml')
```

and see that the text I am interested in is wrapped in p tags,

[image]

but when I run `soup.find_all('p')`, the only return I get is the closing paragraph.

How can I extract the paragraph text within? What am I missing?

These are the paragraphs I am trying to extract:

[image]

I tried also with selenium using:

```
chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chrome_options.add_argument("--headless")
chrome_driver = os.getcwd() + "\\chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options = chrome_options, executable_path = chrome_driver)
driver.get(url)
page = driver.page_source
page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page,'xml')
div=page_soup.find_all('p')
[a.text for a in div]
```

Comment: Looks like the data on that page is loaded using JavaScript. Try using [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/) instead of `requests` (which won't give you the dynamic content). You also haven't stated which data you're interested in? Is it all the `p` tags? It seems there are 5 such tags on the page, but only 1 (the first one) is in the raw HTML source, the rest are generated dynamically.

Comment: thank you for suggestion. Selenium returns same issue, and I cannot locate the specific tags

Comment: You need to [edit] your question with the new code you are using.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.

The body of the site comes from a `<script>` tag that holds a `JSON` but with a funky encoding.

That said tag has an `id` of "ng-lseg-state", which means this is Angular's custom HTML encoding.

You can target the `<script>` tag with `BeautifulSoup` and parse it with the `json` module.

Then, however, you need to deal with Angular's encoding. One way, a bit crude thou, is to chain a bunch of `.replace()` methods.

Here's how:

```py
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033"
script = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml").find("script", {"id": "ng-lseg-state"})
article = json.loads(script.string.replace("&q;", '"'))
main_key = "G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v1/pages?parameters=newsId%3D14850033&a;path=news-article"
article_body = article[main_key]["body"]["components"][1]["content"]["newsArticle"]["value"]
decoded_body = (
    article_body
    .replace('&l;', '<')
    .replace('&g;', '>')
    .replace('&q;', '"')
)
print(BeautifulSoup(decoded_body, "lxml").find_all("p")[22].getText())
```

This outputs:

```
Essentra plc is a FTSE 250 company and a leading global provider of essential components and solutions.&a;#160; Organised into three global divisions, Essentra focuses on the light manufacture and distribution of high volume, enabling components which serve customers in a wide variety of end-markets and geographies.
```

However, as I've said, this is not the best approach, as I'm not entirely sure how to deal with a bunch of other characters, namely:

- `&amp;a;#160;`
- `&amp;a;amp;`
- `&amp;s;`

just to name a few. But [I've already asked about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67038324/how-to-decode-angulars-custom-html-encoding).

EDIT:

Here's a fully working code based on the answer to my question, mentioned above.

```
import html
import json

import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def unescape(decoded_html):
    char_mapping = {
        '&a;': '&',
        '&q;': '"',
        '&s;': '\'',
        '&l;': '<',
        '&g;': '>',
    }
    for key, value in char_mapping.items():
        decoded_html = decoded_html.replace(key, value)
    return html.unescape(decoded_html)


url = "https://www.londonstockexchange.com/news-article/ESNT/date-for-fy-2020-results-announcement/14850033"
script = BeautifulSoup(requests.get(url).text, "lxml").find("script", {"id": "ng-lseg-state"})
payload = json.loads(unescape(script.string))
main_key = "G.{{api_endpoint}}/api/v1/pages?parameters=newsId%3D14850033&path=news-article"
article_body = payload[main_key]["body"]["components"][1]["content"]["newsArticle"]["value"]
print(BeautifulSoup(article_body, "lxml").find_all("p")[22].getText())
```